# Jenkins fails to restart

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I was working on granting permission on Jenkins, I edited org.jenkins-ci.plist file in order to grant permission. Then restarted Jenkins by using `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://localhost:8080`

The webpage gave me this error.

```
org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:43)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:889)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:794)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:217)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:124)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder$TaskImpl.run(InitializerFinder.java:184)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:878)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.invoke(InitializerFinder.java:120)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD.init(SSHD.java:144)
    ... 13 more
```

Since then I can't even use Jenkins-CLI nor jenkins itself.

What should I do to fix this?

And What should I do to avoid having the same errors when I need to change permission and restart jenkins in the future?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I'm using Mac OS Mountain Lion 10.8, and using Jenkins 1.474

Comment: which os are you running on? windows/linux? which version of jenkins you are using?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS Mountain Lion 10.8
and Jenkins 1.474

Comment: Its bug reported in jenkins on Mac, please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably reported bug in jenkins. check [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12338), you can revert your changes and/or try to older version of jenkins.

Comment: i'll try the older versions. It's weird tho, restarting jenkins did not cause any problems in other mac pcs, only this one..

Comment: btw, how can i reinstall jenkins? do i just have to delete the Jenkins directory and install the pkg file?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea for mac, i used to deploy war directly in tomcat serevr

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on Debian... 
For Jenkins adding & granting permissions to Jenkins users
When enabling security on jenkins make sure you check 
- "enable sign up", or something like that
- the option to store users, for example "jenkins own database"
- make sure that anonymous user have minimum read permission

Grant Jenkins permission on PC
Must say that I don't know the directory structure on Mac, but if it's similar to Linux...
- you should have a file called jenkins, on Linux is in /etc/sysconfig or /etc/default and in this file change JENKINS_USER to whatever user you want.But you must be sure that that user exists on PC, on Linux the user must be in /etc/passwd

- change permissions to Jenkins home,webroot and logs, on Linux with:
  chown -R user:user /var/lib/jenkins 
  chown -R user:user /var/cache/jenkins
  chown -R user:user /var/log/jenkins

PS: I gave the Linux examples because it's easily to explain, again I don't have experience on Mac.

But it should work...

Answer (score 0):

[image: try to delete and then refresh the website with your localhost address]

Trying to delete the folder contents and then refresh your website with your local host address,then you will see some unlock tip with the password appear in the terminal. Then go ahead to reinstall your plugins . Hope will help you!